# XML white space formatting in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, transformer-model

I've got problem with formatting white space in Java. I add new attribute to my file, but it hasn't correct format.

```
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("name");
    attr.setValue("name");
    element.setAttributeNode(attr);
    element.setTextContent("Something=" + this.thumbnailCacheSize);

    NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("mbean");
    Node e = items.item(0);
    e.appendChild(element);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(filepath);

    transformer.transform(source,result);
```

It should look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <server>
   <mbean code="code" name="name">
     <attribute name="name3">Something3=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name2">Something2=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name1">Something1=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name">Something=500</attribute>
   </mbean>
 </server>
```

But is like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <server>
 <mbean code="code" name="name">
     <attribute name="name3">Something3=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name2">Something2=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name1">Something1=500</attribute>
   <attribute name="name">Something=500</attribute>
 </mbean>
 </server>
```

When I used:
     transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <server>
 <mbean code="code" name="name">
     <attribute name="name3">Something3=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name2">Something2=500</attribute>
     <attribute name="name1">Something1=500</attribute>
   <attribute name="name">Something=500</attribute>
     </mbean>
 </server>
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you didn't have elements confusingly named "attribute"...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); // enable indent
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4"); // 4 is indent space (default is zero)
```

Comment: It works, but now, I've got correct indent in <mbean>, but in <attribute... /> no. (Like in my post above.)